# Using the Rally API to create an artifact at the bottom of the backlog

Tags: rally

We've used the Ruby Rally API to create user stories, but these appear to by default be located at the top of the backlog.  Is there a way to use the API / create and have it appear at the bottom of the backlog instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is a REST endpoint in the Rally Webservices API to "rank above" or "rank below". For example, you can use the following REST request to re-rank a defect, relative to another Defect, whose reference you know:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.25/defect/3850797404.js?rankAbove=/defect/3859484383.js&fetch=Name,FormattedID,Rank

The standard [Rally Ruby REST API](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/ruby-toolkit-rally-rest-api) does not have access to this endpoint, unfortunately.

If you're interested however there is a new "alpha" [Rally Ruby REST API](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/ruby-toolkit-rally-rest-api-json) that serializes requests using JSON and not XML. The "rankAbove and rankBelow" endpoints are available to the Ruby JSON API. Another advantage of the JSON-based Ruby API is that because JSON is so much more compact than XML, it offers performance benefits over the older XML-based Ruby REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mark's note, in rally_api (the new gem), you can query for objects sorted by rank to get the lowest item.  Then if you have objectA that is lowest or a place holder story that is a cut line, you can call:
someobject.rank_below(objectA)

Comment: Thank you both.  We've successfully used the old Ruby REST API to get an ordered list of items, e.g.  "rally.find_all(:hierarchical_requirement, :order => "rank ASC", :project => project, :fetch => true)".  We'd also used the "artifact.update(:rank => rank)" to update the rank, so I might see if I can use both of these in conjunction with each other to achieve what I want with the old API.